# Get cell to the right of current month in Excel

Tags: excel, date, reference

I'm pretty new to Excel, that question is probably easy, but I dont know what to do :-(.
So this is what I have:

```
Date        Numbers
01.09.11      10   
01.10.11      20
01.11.11      30
01.12.11      40
```

Now what I want is in another cell: Get the number of the date, where the date's month is the current month. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your dates are **strings** of the form "dd.mm.yy", you can use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(9,VALUE(MID(A1:A4,4,2)),0))
```

where the 9 is the month number you want to look up.  Enter this as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, you want to match the current month, so incorporating @JMax's suggestion works:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(MONTH(TODAY()),VALUE(MID(A1:A4,4,2)),0))
```

To clear up any confusion, `MID()` returns a string, which by itself will not return a match for the number value returned by `MONTH(TODAY())`.  However, if you stick the `MID()` function inside a `VALUE()` function, the string returned by `MID()` will be converted into a number value.  E.g., "09" becomes the number 9, "10" becomes the number 10.  This allows you to match the number value returned by `MONTH(TODAY())`.

However, if your dates are entered as **dates** with format dd.mm.yy in your sheet instead of as strings, then you can use the same strategy but with a different matching term:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(A1:A4),0))
```

Enter this as an array formula.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the *current* month, so instead of "9", it should be something like `MONTH(TODAY())`. Yet, this is a good solution :)

Comment: thanks, this is probably the right answer, and all my dates are formatted as dd.mm.yy, but I think "MID" makes numbers out of the dates, and thats why it doesn't work. Can I get around that somehow?

Comment: @JMax, right you are.  Fixed above.  Thanks!
ka2011r, I edited my answer to explain how my solution addresses this issue.  Everything should be in working order now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still, it doesn't work, I get an #NV error. Did you try this solution? When I just enter `=VALUE(MID(A1:A4;4;2))` as an array formula it prints 17. Excel seems to treat the dates as values (the number of days from year 2000 or something like that.. )

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  Your dates are entered in Excel as Dates, not as strings.  Excel treats dates as a number value, counting up from 1-1-1900.  For that reason, MID() won't do the trick for your data, but there should be a simpler solution.  I'll try to whip up something in the next few minutes.

Comment: I added a solution at the bottom of my post that should work for you.  Sorry this took so many iterations.